# When Using the "Search Organization Content" bar in a google site, is there a way to prevent or filter certain types of results?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-sites

So I am trying to set up a simple "Hub page" for the company I work for and we use a LOT of google workspace documents, sheets, folders etc. I thought setting up a search bar using the "search organization content" would be perfect since all of our employee drives are tied to the organization. The problem is, that emails come up as search results, including sensitive ones sent to HR. I am trying to find a way to disable Gmail and google groups results and instead only show PDFs, Sheets, Docs, and other Workspace related documentation instead.

I have contacted workspace support and was informed that there is not a feature currently to disable specific types of results, but was unable to tell me if there was a way using appscript or other coding related solutions. They suggested I come here to ask for help.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd give a reproducible example unless you have an organization set up in google workspace as well, but basically, if you were to search for my name on our company site, because you knew I created a document but couldn't recall the name of said document, you would get that as a result as well as any emails I have sent recently or conversations in Google Groups. 

considering our organization uses email and groups to communicate with HR regarding any number or private matters, you can see how this is a problem

Comment: If you are looking for an example of code I have used, I havent used any yet as I'm not sure where I would apply it. I'm hoping to atleast get some direction on where I would put a script so I can start trying things and seeing if they work.

Comment: Then how did you determine what is being returned by your searches?

Comment: There is an intranet-style search bar that exists in google sites. Google Workspace Support directed me here to find out if there is a way to specify the results. as it stands, the functionality that Google has given me is, "do you want a search bar? yes or no" and then "should we search just this site or all of your organization files?"

I want to search our organization drives, pdfs, google sheets, docs, etc. which is what I thought that search bar did, but for whatever crazy reason, google includes emails in these search results as well.